# Flatten rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, date, rows, range, flatten

I need to flatten or collapse the rows from either tables before I can join both tables and perform calculation

TABLE - A

```
StartDate   EndDate        ValueA

2/1/2012    2/1/2012    1

2/2/2012    2/2/2012    2

2/3/2012    2/3/2012    3

2/7/2012    2/8/2012    4
```

TABLE - B

```
startdate   enddate        ValueB

2/1/2012    2/1/2012    4

2/2/2012    2/3/2012    5

2/7/2012    2/7/2012    6

2/8/2012    2/8/2012    7**
```

RESULT

```
StartDate   EndDate        ValueA   ValueB

2/1/2012    2/1/2012    calc    calc

2/2/2012    2/3/2012    calc    calc

2/7/2012    2/8/2012    calc    calc
```

for a record in table A: if there are multiple records in table B which are within the start and EndDAte of table A, then I need to "flatten" or "collapse" those records in table B before I can join to Table A to perform my calculations

Similarly, the same condition can exist the other way, such that table A has multiple records, that fall within Start and EndDate of table B, so in this case I need to flatten those records in table A so that it conforms to Start and End Date of table B.

I am able to acheive this using multiple cursors but the performance is pathetic, and I am hoping that someone would be able to provide a better solution to this problem

I hope my question is making sense to you guys

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you plan on "collapsing" the records?  SUM()?  AVG()?  Are they distinct values that need extra columns like a PIVOT table?

Comment: This looks like a gaps and islands problem except I don't understand the result. Why isn't the first row `2/1/2012 - 2/3/2012`

Comment: The calculation is little complicated, but it is based on the columns from the two tables.

Comment: The problem is I need to perform this calculation on the most granular period available in either of the tables. For example, I have the data for PeriodStart 2/1 to PeriodEnd 2/1 in both the tables, so I dont need to do anywork on this row, I can simply do my calculation. Now in second case, in table A I have two rows from 2/2 to 2/2 and 2/3/ to 2/3, but in table B I have one row from 2/2-2/3. I have no way of breaking the data in tableB to two rows, but I can combine the data in table A for those two rows and then do my calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this one a shot (prob. not the most efficient... as I was in a hurry):

```
drop table tablea
drop table tableb

CREATE TABLE TableA (startdate DATE, enddate DATE, value INT)
CREATE TABLE TableB (startdate DATE, enddate DATE, value INT)

INSERT TableA SELECT '2/1/2012', '2/1/2012', 1
INSERT TableA SELECT '2/2/2012', '2/2/2012', 2
INSERT TableA SELECT '2/3/2012', '2/3/2012', 3
INSERT TableA SELECT '2/7/2012', '2/8/2012', 4


INSERT TableB SELECT '2/1/2012', '2/1/2012', 4
INSERT TableB SELECT '2/2/2012', '2/3/2012', 5
INSERT TableB SELECT '2/7/2012', '2/7/2012', 6
INSERT TableB SELECT '2/8/2012', '2/8/2012', 7


;WITH tablea_cte AS (
  SELECT
    StartDate
    , EndDate
  FROM
    TableA a
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableB b WHERE b.startdate >= a.startdate and b.enddate <= a.enddate)  
),
tableb_cte as (
  SELECT
    StartDate
    , EndDate
  FROM
    TableB b
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableA a WHERE a.startdate >= b.startdate and a.enddate <= b.enddate)  
),
tableab_cte AS (
  SELECT * FROM  tableb_cte union select * FROM tablea_cte
),
sumab_cte as (
  SELECT
    ab.startdate
    , ab.enddate
    , calcA = (SELECT SUM (value) FROM TableA a where a.startdate >= ab.startdate and a.enddate <= ab.enddate)
    , calcB = (SELECT SUM (value) FROM TableB b where b.startdate >= ab.startdate and b.enddate <= ab.enddate)
  FROM
    tableab_cte ab
)
select * from sumab_cte
```

Comment: You can change 'SUM' with whatever operation you want to do~